# How to use git hub in Mac Terminal

Tags: git, github

I have just started using the git hub.
I know my question would be the most basic question on git hub, but I couldn't figure out myself, so I am asking for your help.

I googled a lot looking for the basic guidelines of how to actually 'use' the github with Mac OS's Terminal. But probably with the lack of my searching skills, I couldn't find the exact description of what I am looking for.

So, I have done the initial setups.
-I created the repository on my git account and committed my files that are saved on my Mac and pushed them. So my git account on the Web has the files I have uploaded. Also, I cloned the repository file on my Mac.

But after that, if I want to reenter the terminal, how do I 1) access the git account then 2)enter the repository I am working on?

This is so so basic, but your help will save me.. Thank you :)

Comment: `cd` to the directory where your repo is (e.g. where the `.git` file is). Then you can perform any commands. Try `git status` to check if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your second question then the first question.

Here is an easy way to enter your repository.

1. Open both your **terminal** and **finder** in your mac.
2. Find that **repository folder** in your finder.
3. In your terminal, type `cd` and then space. Then drag your repository folder **from finder to terminal**, right next to it.
4. Press Enter.

Now, your terminal is in your repository.

Cloning a repository to the local workspace doesn't require logging in.

When you try to push to your remote repository that you've cloned using:

```
git push
```

it'll ask you about your email / password to check if it is really you who is pushing to the remote branch.